# Twitter API not returning GET trends/place based on WOEID

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, woe-id

Using Twitter API. Trying to get trending topics based on a WOEID.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place

If I do a global search using "1" I get general trending topics on Twitter, as expected.

I also get results if I use the WOEID for the entire USA: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/trends/place.json?id=23424977

However, if I try any WOEID smaller than that (e.g. New York: 2347591) I get a code 34 error: "Sorry, that page does not exist."

Does that mean there are no trending topics for any area smaller than the entire USA? I can't seem to get any.

Any insight would be valuable.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: same error i am getting when using the twitter api